# Firebase anonymous authentication timing issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase anonymous authentication to read the data from a Firebase database.

The issue is that the code is not consistently reading data from Firebase using `readFromFirebase` method in `onComplete`.

Sometimes it is reading and sometimes it is throwing error.

> DatabaseError: This client does not have permission to perform this operation

I can see below in logs:

> Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event.
>
> Notifying auth state listeners.
>
> Notified 1 auth state listeners.
>
> Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.

Looks like problem in:

```
 geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {


  Task<AuthResult> authResultTask = mAuth.signInAnonymously()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        readFromFirebase( techCategory, locLatLng);
                     } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());

                    }

                }
```